# Customize @User.Identity.NewMethodHere() to return a user first and last name, using ef code first and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I don't even know how to word this question...

I am using the newish asp.net identity provider. I would like to be able to pull in certain data from the logged in user on just about every view of my site. My simplified model is this:

**User.cs**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

In razor views, I get check to see if someone is logged in and then use:

```
@User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

Which will obviously return my username. I would like to make a way I could call @User.Identity.GetUserFirstAndLastName() or something like that. Is there a way I can add a call like that? I would really hate to have to ViewBag the value for every single view I have.

Comment: Take a look at [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to wdosanjos for pointing me to extenstion method. After reading the link and googling some more I came up with this:

```
public static class IdentityApplicationUserExtension
{
    public static User GetApplicationUser(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(new MyDbContext()));
        return manager.FindById<User>(identity.GetUserId());
    }
}
```

User is the ApplicationUser class.

In a razor view all i need to do is this:

```
 @User.Identity.GetApplicationUser().AnyColumnFieldHere
```

Super simple after all!